# Grub Installation failed - Invalid Argument

Tags: boot, system-installation, grub2, boot-loader

Been stuck on installation of multiple distros for a while.
The installation always fails when running the grub installer and the syslog says:

```
grub-installer: info: Installing Grub on '/dev/mmcblk0'
grub-installer: info: grub-install does not support --no-floppy
grub-installer: info: Running chroot /target grub-install --force "/dev/mmcblk0"
grub-installer: Installing for x86_64-efi platform
grub-installer: Could not prepare Boot variable: Invalid argument
grub-installer: grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
grub-installer: error: Running 'grub-install --force "/dev/mmcblk0"' failed.
```

I'm not the most experienced with Linux, although I can somewhat find my way around, but I'm quite lost right now and a push in the right direction would be helpful and much appreciated.

Currently trying to install KDE Neon
Working on a GPD Pocket 2 (which is probably the issue)

If you need any more info let me know, I usually post on Reddit so I'm probably missing something.

Thanks in advance as well!